# issue in using reactive apps with lambda

Tags: functional-programming, mono, project-reactor, reactive

I am pretty new to use of reactive in Java. Here below is the issue that I am facing.

I have developed a springboot-REST application with contoller, service and repository layer with R2DBC driver.

```
public interface ItemRepository extends R2dbcRepository<Item, String>
```

This repo is called from the service layer.
The service layer has the following codebase
(Logically I dont need monoItemFromDB in this scenario, but just ignore that logical issue as I am more interested on the technical aspect)

```
public Mono<Item> modifyItem(Mono<Item> itemMono, int id ) {
    Mono<Item> monoItemFromDB = itemRepo.findById(id);
    return itemMono
            .flatMap(item -> {
                monoItemFromDB.subscribe(dbItem -> item.setId(dbItem.getId()));
                return itemRepo.save(item);
            });
}
```

The above method works well and the data gets saved in the embedded Database.
But the below code which is a bit different from the above one, does not save the data in the DB.

```
public Mono<Item> modifyItem(Mono<Item> itemMono, int id ) {
    Mono<Item> monoItemFromDB = itemRepo.findById(id);
    monoItemFromDB.subscribe(dbItem -> {
        itemMono.flatMap(item -> {
            item.setId(dbItem.getId());
            return itemRepo.save(item);
        });
    });
    return monoItemFromDB; //Ignore what is returned as saving is the only point of concern
}
```

In the first scenario, I am flattening the itemMono and then doing the 2 step process of subscribing on the monoItemFromDB to get the id and saving the item to the repo.
In the second scenario, I am subscribing over the monoItemFromDB and then doing the 2 step process of flattening the itemMono to set the id and saving the item to the repo

Request someone to explain the blunder I am doing in the second way of writing the method.

Thanks in Advance!
Sriram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not use `subscribe` to do any additional work. *Subscribe* is called by all the intermediary steps like `.flatMap()` and it should not exist in your code except the very last step that launches everything. If you have a WebFlux app then you *should not* have it at all because that's WebFlux job to subscribe.

Also you return the first `monoItemFromDB` ignoring the next steps.

The could should be:

```
public Mono<Item> modifyItem(Mono<Item> itemMono, int id ) {
    Mono<Item> monoItemFromDB = itemRepo.findById(id);
    Mono<Item> monoItemSaved = monoItemFromDB.flatMap(dbItem -> {
        return itemMono.flatMap(item -> {
            item.setId(dbItem.getId());
            return itemRepo.save(item);
        });
    }); 
    return monoItemSaved;
}
```

Or you can start (*subscribe to*) both at the same time:

```
public Mono<Item> modifyItem(Mono<Item> itemMono, int id ) {
    return itemRepo.findById(id).zip(itemMono).flatMap(both -> {
            Item item = both.getT2();
            Item dbItem = both.getT1();
            item.setId(dbItem.getId());
            return itemRepo.save(item);
        });
    }); 
}
```

PS your first example worked because (1) you returned the mono with flatMap assembled into it (not the mono before the subscribe). And (2) it was fast/slow enough that you didn't notice that in some cases it may save an item without a correct `id` set.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed response. It was giving a good clarity. But, still, I dont get the following 2 points 1. "you returned the mono with flatMap assembled into it (not the mono before the subscribe)." - What do you mean by "not the mono before the subscribe"
2. "it was fast/slow enough that you didn't notice that in some cases it may save an item without a correct id set." - Do you mean that before the id is obtained from the DB, there is a chance for the data to get saved in the DB?

Comment: `x = itemRepo.findById(...)` is one instance, `y = monoItemFromDB.subscribe(..)`. They are independent. You return `x`. `monoItemFromDB.subscribe(dbItem -> item.setId(dbItem.getId()));` starts in a new thread, which may or may not finish before you call `itemRepo.save(item)`

Comment: Perfect point to note. Thanks a ton Igor!